# iOS ImageView unwanted resize after NavigationController change

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, storyboard

I'm just starting my journey with iOS development.

I have navigation controller with 3 ViewControllers (1 main and 2 children). In my MainViewController i have ImageView inside another View container.

ImageView isn't link with Obj-C code (just static image). After pressing BarButton to change ViewController my image is resized (50% of default width and height). Of course when i back to MainViewController image is still small.

The weirdest think: It's working correctly in simulator, but not on my real device (iPhone 4)

Do you know what cause this weird behavior?

Comment: There is not enough data in this question to say anything. How do you position everything? Are you using autolayouts?

Comment: Yes, I'am using Auto Layout feature. ImageView is inside another view (width and height - march parent). This View also has constreins (lock width/height [300], top margin and center horizontal).

Comment: Difficult to guess anything without knowledge about these constraints. Set your `mainviewcontroller.view.backgroundcolor` to something, check how it acts, same with each views which are between `mainviewcontroller.view` and your `imageView`. The top one (closest to `mainviewcontroller.view`) which is behaving in a wrong way has wrong constraints set.

Comment: **Only** `ImageView` is smaller. Other elements in container (view) are the the same as they should be.